# add hyperlink in excel to local file using HYPERLINK function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

In my excel file I want to add hyperlink to the local pdf file and they are 10000 pdf files.
My folder which contains all the pdfs is like this

```
/H
|----5_4131_1_merge_recog.pdf
|----5_4132_1_merge_recog.pdf
|----5_4133_1_merge_recog.pdf
|----......
```

And my excel file looks like

```
ID       pdf
4131    
4132
4133
4134
4135
```

So I am using `=HYPERLINK`function to add hyperlinks in pdf column

```
=HYPERLINK("H/5_"&A2&"_1_merge_recog.pdf")
```

which generates the hyperlink like but unable to open the pdf by clicking on it. As there are multiple rows so I want to use the cell for generating the hyperlinks

> H/5_4131_1_merge_recog.pdf

Comment: Your Path looks to be incorrect.  It should be either like `C:\Path\To\Your\File\Filename.pdf` or `\\NetworkDeviceName\ShareName\Path\To\Your\File\FileName.pdf`

Comment: I am working on MAC so the path is users/expether/H/5.pdf

Comment: That's an important detail.   Add it to your question